# Remove Awstats data from previous months in compliance with privacy policy

Tags: cpanel, webserver, privacy-policy, awstats

In cPanel, in Raw Access section I have following configuration. Which I guess means, Remove all the logs of visitors data at the end of month. And it is showing only the data of Feb-2017 in .gz files. This is quite understandable.

> [image]

Now, if I check Awstats under Cpanel, it is showing visitor statistics of Jan-2017 also. **Now, since our system has removed the log data of previous month, from where Awstats is collecting these data and showing in statistics?** How can I remove all the data of visitors at the end of each month, so I can write in website's privacy policy that, we remove all your data after 30 days? Very very Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [Awstats FAQ](http://www.awstats.org/docs/awstats_faq.html#FAQ-COM500) has the information that you are looking for.  Awstats maintains history in text files located in its [DataDir (data directory)](http://www.awstats.org/docs/awstats_config.html#DirData).

To delete old months of data, go to that directory and delete the history files for the old months.   They are typically named `awstatsMMYYYY.txt`  Next time awstats runs, it won't have those stats to include in its output.